# Python keep only alphanumeric words from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words resembling the following

```
    mylist=["hi", "h_ello", "how're", "you", "@list"]
```

I would like to pull out all of the non-alpha numeric characters to give a results such as:

```
                  "h_ello", "how're", "@list"
```

Please note I have a much longer list in real life, and it contains some non-alpha numeric instances such as ~, ?, >, =, + etc.

Does anyone know how to do this ,please?
Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Use `str.isalpha()`

**Ex:**

```
mylist=["hi", "h_ello", "how're", "you", "@list"]
print([i for i in mylist if not i.isalpha()])
```

**Output:**

```
['h_ello', "how're", '@list']
```

Comment: amazing! thank you ! I thought it would be much more complicated - apologies if this was a stuppid question - thank you !

Comment: @Fern_2018, you can also use `isalnum` method like in my answer.

Comment: @Rakesh, `'a1'.isalpha()` will return `False` with `isalpha` method.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut. According to OP's example only alpha chars are required. if OP needs alpha  + numerical the `isalpha` is useful

Comment: @Rakesh, no,  because `'a1'.isalpha()` will return `False` and it's alphanumerical

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `list comprehension` in combination with `isalnum()` function.

```
mylist=["hi", "h_ello", "how're", "you", "@list"]
print([i for i in mylist if not i.isalnum()])
```

Output

```
['h_ello', "how're", '@list']
```

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalnum#str.isalnum):

> `str.isalnum()`
>   Return true if all characters in the string are
>   alphanumeric and there is at least one character, false otherwise. A
>   character c is alphanumeric if one the following returns True:
>   `c.isalpha()`, `c.isdecimal()`, `c.isdigit()`, or `c.isnumeric()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` with `re`:

```
import re
mylist=["hi", "h_ello", "how're", "you", "@list"]
new_list = list(filter(lambda x:re.findall('[\W_]', x), mylist))
```

Output:

```
['h_ello', "how're", '@list']
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you go for isalnum or regex , Here i tried a little different approach just for fun, This is not for production code it will take time, I just tried to show you a different way :

```
import unicodedata
import sys

mylist = ["hi", "h_ello", "how're", "you", "@list"]


def translate(text_):
    pun=[i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')]

    if True in [True if ord(i) in pun else False for i in text_ ]:
        return text_


print(list(filter(lambda x:x,[translate(i) for i in mylist])))
```

output:

```
['h_ello', "how're", '@list']
```