# only keep words in a list which is an element of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains list as elements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'q': [['', 'Id'], [', ', 'Be', ', '], [', ', ''], ['ProgramServiceStatusId', '']]})
```

I want to only keep the elements which contains alphanumeric characters. 
the expected output would be

```
      q
0   [Id]
1   [Be]
2   []
3   [ProgramServiceStatusId]
```

I referred this question, but it requires two loops:
[Python keep only alphanumeric words from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215117/python-keep-only-alphanumeric-words-from-list) 
First one to iterate over df column and second one to iterate over individual list. 
I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['q'] = df['q'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i.isalpha()])
print (df)
                          q
0                      [Id]
1                      [Be]
2                        []
3  [ProgramServiceStatusId]
```